# how to get value of a field in object in android

Tags: java, android

I am new to android. I am working on simple android project where I am using `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute` method in which I am getting the result from `doInBackground()` in parameter `result`.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try {
            Log.d(result.toString(),"resultvalue");
            if (result != null) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve any data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

when I log the `result` as `String` I am getting the value

```
   {"success":1,"message":"Successfully registered the user","error_code":"200"}
```

but I want to display the value in `message` and I am unable to get it from object `result`. Can someone help me. I am stuck with the problem.

Comment: You should parse this

Comment: Are you sure the response will always will be a json

Answer (score 2):

The response you got is a JSONObject. You should create a JSONObject with that string and get the value you need.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result.toString());
jsonObject.getInt("success");
jsonObject.getString("message");
jsonObject.getInt("error_code");
```

PS: You should not use Log.d like that. The name should be first parameter not second and the value should be second not first.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the JSON and then display it:

```
try {
    // Log.d(result.toString(), "resultvalue");
    if (result != null) {
        // ADDED CODE IS HERE:
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result.toString());
        String message = json.getString("message");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Unable to retrieve any data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // YOU MAY WANT TO MAKE A TOAST HERE AS WELL
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To be thorough, if an exception happens while parsing the message, you may want to also make some sort of error toast to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse result to `JsonObject`

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        try {
            Log.d(result.toString(),"resultvalue");
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result.toString());
            if (jsonObject.getInt("success")==1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve any data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to always have generic Exception handler so that if there is any other exception besides expected exceptions then application wouldnt stop abruptly and you can display appropriate user friendly message to user and handle it internally as per your application requirement (dump in files or database for collecting reports with user consent etc).

First parameter to Log.d is always a TAG which can be used to search logcat. I am using TAG, you can use anything that suits you and makes it easier to search logs.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try {
        if (result != null) {
            // display result.toString() only after checking is null or not
            Log.d("TAG", result.toString());
            if  (result.toString().length() > 0) {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result.toString());
                if (json != null && json.getString("message") != null) {
                     String message = json.getString("message");
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // TOAST for empty result or capture this for future analysis
                }
            } else {
                // TOAST for empty result or capture this for future analysis
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve any data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Have a toast to display user friendly message
        // Capture this in files or DB so can be used to report on user consent
        Log.d("TAG", "Exception Details: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Have a toast to display user friendly message
        // Capture this in files or DB so can be used to report on user consent
        Log.d("TAG", "Exception Details: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```